# Failed to build dlib ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, streamlit, dlib

I am not able run my streamlit app and encountering the error

```
Collecting mdurl~=0.1

  Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)

Building wheels for collected packages: dlib, face-recognition-models

  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): started

  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I uninstall the dlib
And install cmake and then again install dlib
Still getting same error

```
Collecting mdurl~=0.1

  Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)

Building wheels for collected packages: dlib, face-recognition-models

  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): started

  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus

      compilation terminated.

      gmake[2]: *** [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/build.make:650: dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/cpu_dlib.cpp.o] Error 1

      gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

      gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:144: dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/all] Error 2

      gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>

          main()

        File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main

          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])

        File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel

          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel

          return self._build_with_temp_dir(

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir

          self.run_setup()

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup

          exec(code, locals())

        File "<string>", line 218, in <module>

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup

          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup

          return run_commands(dist)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands

          dist.run_commands()

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands

          self.run_command(cmd)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1001, in run_command

          super().run_command(command)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command

          cmd_obj.run()

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run

          self.run_command("build")

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command

          self.distribution.run_command(command)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1001, in run_command

          super().run_command(command)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command

          cmd_obj.run()

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run

          self.run_command(cmd_name)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command

          self.distribution.run_command(command)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1001, in run_command

          super().run_command(command)

        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-b7jlrmki/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command

          cmd_obj.run()

        File "<string>", line 130, in run

        File "<string>", line 170, in build_extension

        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call

          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j16']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

      [end of output]

  

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib

  Building wheel for face-recognition-models (setup.py): started

  Building wheel for face-recognition-models (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

  Created wheel for face-recognition-models: filename=face_recognition_models-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=100566173 sha256=d8291ec22bf741b111cef52d870c35c831bab9f7714c70f5a7f84f49fa6f3ada

  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-_mnd73k6/wheels/22/a8/60/4a2aeb763d63f50190f4c4e07069a22245347eeafdb3a67551
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error How to resolve this error